# /etc/environment not being read into PATH variable

Tags: ubuntu, path, xorg

In Ubuntu the path variable is stored in /etc/environment.  This is mine (I've made no changes to it, this is the system default):

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

but when I examine my PATH variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/dan/bin:/home/dan/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/X11
```

You'll notice /usr/games is missing (it was there up until a few days ago).  My /etc/profile makes no mention of PATH.  My ~/.profile is the default and only has:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

This only happens in gnome, not in tty1-6.  This is missing from both gnome terminal and when I try to call applications from the applications dropdown.  Anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your shell is bash, it pays no attention to /etc/environment at least as far as the manpage and an `strace bash` says. Indeed, I can find no program listed that does mention /etc/environment.

I've run into similar situations under Ubuntu where there are 4 or more levels of indirection pointing to the datum that you really want. Often times I find it easier to fix the proximate, rather than the ultimate source of the datum.

In this case, modifying your personal path in ~/.profile is in fact the proper way to do it since at least [V7 Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix).

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with that solution, but that is a user level solution for a system level problem.  I would actually like to address the problem.  There are plenty of places I could just override the PATH variable, like /etc/profile as well, but that has nothing to do with PATH on Ubuntu, so I would prefer to address it where the problem lies.

Comment: Today I have the same problem as the OP:  I rebooted and suddenly the correct `PATH` is no longer available in `bash`.  It was yesterday.  Something is actually broken...

Answer (score 1):

No one really answered the root cause of this issue. @msw does have the correct solution however I want to explain what is going on.

In ubuntu when you use an application that is pam aware it will run through the list of modules listed in /etc/pam.d/* one of these modules used during login controls what environment variables get set. `/etc/pam.d/login` or `/etc/pam.d/su` are likely the modules that you triggered when logging into your user. In these files `/etc/login.defs` is used to determine your base environment as shown here.

```
#
# *REQUIRED*  The default PATH settings, for superuser and normal users.
#
# (they are minimal, add the rest in the shell startup files)
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I didn't look far enough into where this actually gets triggered in pam but this should help clear things up. You may also have setting that override the above in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` as well as several other locations.

http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-pam-works if you really want to get into how pam works and how to identify what programs use it.